# How to Transform a Blob to An Image in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, blob, converters

i want to display an image stored in mysql database
the problem is that i can't convert the blob format into a Uint8list ; i searched and found soulitions but none of them works
Grab the blob from JSON:

var blob = yourJSONMapHere['yourJSONKeyHere'];

var image = BASE64.decode(blob); // image is a Uint8List

Now, use image in a Image.memory

new Container( child: new Image.memory(image));

this soulition didn't work because base64.decode need a string source not a blob file to convert

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it is relatable to this particular case but had similar issue with Cloud Firestore.

Created blob for storing in this way:

```
Blob myBlob = Blob(await audioFile.readAsBytes());
```

saved to Firestore in one field as usual
Then tried to read it back and couldn't figure it out how to get Uint8List from blob I get back from Firestore.

my solution:

```
//extract blob from field of Firestore document
Blob audioBlob = audioDocFromDb.get("fieldName");

//use .bytes on blob from this source
//package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/blob.dart
Uint8List audioBytes = audioBlob.bytes;
```

this worked for me.
In my case I was packing up recorded audio and trying to play it back.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, i know the solution now, after many attempts:
Dont forget to upvote!

Uint8List image = Uint8List.fromList(blob.toBytes());

Image.memory(image);

Answer (score 0):

This function has always saved me for getting bytes from a file that is uploaded to a URL.

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

// urlImageBlob is the URL where our file is hosted.

Uint8List fileBytes = await http.readBytes(Uri.parse(urlImageBlob));

// Display if are image.
Image.memory(fileBytes);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31872596)